# Is there an electric field around neutral atoms?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, atomic-physics, dipole, multipole-expansion

Even if the atom is neutral (equal numbers of protons and electrons), the electrons and nucleus form an electrical dipole, so there is still an electric field around them, even though the total charge is zero. Is this reasoning correct? So, every atom has an electric field, even if it is too weak? If not, why?

Comment: Consider the hydrogen atom in the spherically symmetric 1s state.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In an atom the electrons do not have a position. They are delocalised over the whole atom and in the absence of any external field this results in a symmetric charge distribution. So an isolated neutral atom is spherical and has no external field.

However if you bring two atoms near each other then their charge densities will develop fluctuations that are correlated. That is, both atoms will develop small but non-zero fluctuating dipoles and indeed higher multipoles. The interaction between these is the origin of the [London dispersion force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force). So in these circumstances the atoms do have a fluctuating external field, though the long time average still remains zero.

Comment: So it seems like the "neutral" atom is really neutral due to Quantum Mechanics and the classical electrostatic doesn't work so well (I haven't studied much about Quantum Mechanics). However, why would a symmetrical charge distribution make the atom neutral? Does it has to do with Quantum Mechanics too?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo: An atom is neutral because it has equal amounts of positive and negative charge i.e. equal numbers of protons and electrons. If you ionise the atom by removing an electron then the resulting ion is still spherically symmetrical but now has a net charge (of $-e$). The spherical symmetry just means it it has no electric dipole or higher moments.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. What I meant by neutral, in yhe comment, is that it has no electric field around (caused by the dipole electron-proton). So, there is no such electric field because of Quantum Mechanics, right? What about the symmetrical charge distribution, why would it make there's no electric-field around the atom?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo: Look at [the definition of the dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment). A spherically symmetric charge distribution necessarily has a zero dipole moment.

Comment: I like to think that these fluctuations are not in time, but within a similar analogy between classical and quantum mechanics than for example classical momentum change due to force and the change in wave function oscillations on a potential gradient. Certainly, there is momentum and therefore change of classical quantities wrt. time, but everything is still stationary. In RPA for example, these fluctuations are present as correlation via the doubly excited Slater determinants and the average dipole moment over marginal distribution of a single atom still averages to zero.

Comment: The problem is in timing. Two equal fast atoms may collide and manifest some "interaction potential" outside the atoms. Fast atoms are needed to prevent the atomic polarization with a quasi-static field in case of slow motion. It is possible to achieve in the regime of first Born approximation where only non-perturbed wave functions appear in calculations.

Comment: But if there is an electron in a non-ground state, so something that isn't spherically symmetric, wouldn't there be a field outside?

Comment: The electrical field exists outside the atom, but it quickly decays with distance. There is no certain "border".

Comment: @JohnRennie     In your comment you say "...but now has a net charge (of  $-e$)".  I assume you are saying the resulting ion charge is positive $e$.  By $-e$, do you mean minus the negative electron charge resulting in plus?  I assume that is what you mean.  But is that the right way this to say it is a positive charge, why not say $+e$ which I have seen before.

Comment: @K7PEH: oops, yes, that's a typo and it should be $+e$.

Comment: But there should be right ? Otherwise the concepts of electronegativity will fail. If there is no electric field around the atom, then  a lone electron can just move into the atom without requiring any energy. (Since it will experience neither attraction or repulsion from nucleus and outer electrons respectively)

Answer (score 9):

Strictly speaking, yes, I believe neutral atoms have an electric field (though very weak). For example, if you have a hydrogen atom in the ground state, the absolute magnitude of the wave function of the electron decreases exponentially with radius (for a sufficiently large radius), so there is a (very small) positive total charge within a sphere with an arbitrarily large radius.

Answer (score 5):

Atoms are in the quantum mechanical regime. The electrons around the nucleus occupy [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) ( not orbits) i.e. probability loci where a measurement will find an electron.

These orbitals have quantum numbers that give them shape. When the angular momentum quantum number l is equal to zero, the orbital is isotropic and neutrality is maintained. But for higher l values there are shapes, as seen in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Orbitals_table). Thus the negative charge has a shape, that leaves space for the positive charge of the nucleus to come out, creating positive and negative fields. These are the fields that generate the bonds for molecules, solids and liquids.

**Edit** after comments discussion

It is not simple, because this is a quantum mechanical frame.

Here is a measured [orbital distribution for hydrogen](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-first-image-ever-of-a-hydrogen-atoms-orbital-struc-509684901) , and it is symmetric.

[image: h orbitals]

The difference with the images in the table linked above is due to the fact that the experiment shows a time averaged distribution of the probable locations of the single electron around the proton [for many randomly oriented hydrogen atoms.](https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.213001) At any given time t, the electron will be at a single point with respect to the proton, and a field shape will appear. When two hydrogen atoms approach each other, the proton is not completely shielded by the electron, but an effective potential between the two atoms can be established leading to the bond that makes shared orbitals for the two electrons and creating the stable H2.

So yes, there is an instantaneous spill over field, whose probable strength that depends on the probabilities given by the orbitals .

Comment: Though in the absence of an external field the atom will be in a superposition of all the $p$, $d$, $f$ etc orbitals and will be spherically symmetric. So even with incompletely populated orbitals it still won't any shape other than a sphere.

Comment: @JohnRennie There are spill over fields .  Did you look at the table?

Comment: If you take a isolated boron atom, $1s^22s^22p^1$ then it does not have a single electron in e.g. the $2p_x$ orbital. It has, in effect, a third of an electron in each of the $2p_x$, $2p_y$ and $2p_z$ orbitals and the resulting charge distribution is spherical. The charge distribution only develops a dipole if you apply an external field.

Comment: @JohnRennie  maybe that is why one has H2 but not B2 ?

Comment: $B_2$ is a stable molecule and exists in the gas phase. However it's too reactive to hang around under normal lab conditions.

Comment: @JohnRennie  so the fields appear in conjunction with each other? ( what you call external?)

Comment: @JohnRennie There's nothing stopping you from starting with an electron in any combination of orbitals you want, which will be stable if they all have the same quantum number $n$.  In order to assert it must be spherical symmetric, you need to assume thermal equilibrium or some other nontrivial assumption.

Comment: *"At any given time t, the electron will be at a single point with respect to the proton"* This phrase bothers me to no end and I strongly suspect that it's just plain wrong.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP at time t, the probability of the electron  (point particle) to be at (x,y,z) is given by the complex conjugate square of the wavefunction, seen in the table linked in the answer. One measurement is a point in the image above .

Comment: To think about this in a different way, consider an electron in an infinite potential well in, say, the ground state. If I measure the electric field at some distance from the well, will I keep getting different results corresponding to the electron being at one or another position within the well or will I measure something like $\int_0^a \Psi^*(r)E(r_0-r)\Psi(r)dr$?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP  the electric field is a macroscopic concept, to measure it really y ou will get the integral . an H atom is not an infinite potential well, and to measure any fields  around it one has to come with an analogous detector, another H or another atom . The orbital formulation  gives a visual of this experimental fact, that H is attracted to H and forms H2

Comment: Strictly speaking then, the question of whether or not there is a field around the hydrogen atom in the ground state is sort of unverifiable. We may consider that everything is perfectly symmetrical (in a scenario similar to akhmeteli's answer), but as soon as we introduce a probe, its interaction with the atom completely changes the system and the spherical symmetry is broken. Would you agree with such an interpretation?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP  I tend to "believe" in the orbitals, i.e. the probability distributions, they are angular momentum conservation  shapes .   It is like the double slit, one instance is a  point on the screen , many have a shape. Except we cannot do the single electron experiment. That is there is no spherical symmetry in the hydrogen like wavefunctions for l >0 , if one could look at the same atom many times.